# how to approach SQL query that counts various combination of boolean flags?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table structured like the below, and I want to be able to count all the predefined scenarios I'm searching  for -

[image]

The real data is obviously much more complicated but if for simplicity sake I use a clear data here. I'm struggling to find a smart way of doing that instead of having aggregated table per each "stat".

here's the script for generating the example:

```
declare @persons table(
person_id INT,
country_id INT,
is_adult BIT,
is_fat BIT,
is_tall BIT,
is_bald BIT)

declare @stats table(
    stat_name varchar(max),
    persons_count INT
)

insert @persons
values
    (1000, 12, 1, 0, 1, 0),
    (1001, 15, 1, 0, 0, 1),
    (1002, 12, 0, 1, 1, 0),
    (1003, 20, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    (1004, 15, 0, 1, 0, 1)

insert @stats
values
    ('adults, fat, tall', 0),
    ('adults, fat, tall, bald', 0),
    ('fat, bald', 0),
    ('tall', 0)
```

Thx

Comment: I'm not sure I really follow what you are asking here. Is the data in your `@stats` variable the expected results?

Comment: SELECT FROM WHERE C1 OR C2 OR C3 OR ETCC

Comment: @BogdanSahlean `bit` is *not* a boolean in SQL Server; you can't do `WHERE BitColumn1 OR Bitcolumn2` and get rows where either of the `bit` columns have the value `1`. YOu need to be explicit an compare to `1`/`0`.

Comment: @Larnu I'm looking to fill the 'stats' table with the count of the relevant persons.
I already have predefined stats like 'tall + bald' and 'adult + bald' and 'adult + bald + tall' etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a bit mask for each value and then match on that mask from your stat table:

```sql
DECLARE @persons TABLE(
person_id INT,
country_id INT,
is_adult BIT,
is_fat BIT,
is_tall BIT,
is_bald BIT
, agg AS is_adult + 2 * is_fat + 4 * is_tall + 8 * is_bald
)

DECLARE @stats TABLE(
    stat_name varchar(max),
    persons_count INT, agg int
)

INSERT @persons
VALUES
    (1000, 12, 1, 0, 1, 0),
    (1001, 15, 1, 0, 0, 1),
    (1002, 12, 0, 1, 1, 0),
    (1003, 20, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    (1004, 15, 0, 1, 0, 1)

INSERT @stats
VALUES
    ('adults, fat, tall', 0, 1 + 2 + 4),
    ('adults, fat, tall, bald', 0, 1 + 2 + 4 + 8),
    ('fat, bald', 0, 2 + 8),
    ('tall', 0, 4),
    ('adult,tall', 0, 1 + 4)

SELECT  s.stat_name, count(*)
FROM    @persons p
INNER JOIN @stats s
    ON  s.agg & p.agg = s.agg
GROUP BY s.stat_name
```

i added agg column which is a 4 bit mask of 1 or 0es depending on your is_trait field.
It follows the 2 ** 0, 2 ** 1, 2 ** 2, ... 2 ** N pattern for each new field.
Binary-wise it looks like: 1101 for adult, slim, tall and bald (mask goes from the right).

For the stats, you create same mask of the fields you wanna match.

Finally for the join, you do a bit & (and) operator and check so your result matched. For example: 0111 & 1001 will return bits where both bits in same position is 1, ie: 0001

EDIT: Great username :)

Comment: Although that's a great approach, it didn't fit my needs as the real 'stats' is somehow needs to be collected and not ready like the simple sample, but I've managed to change the structure in order to tackle it so thanks for this interesting one.

BTW I hope you're not falling down :)

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Bitfield stuff is usually not the most SQL-friendly stuff. And lol, so far so good, still waiting in the car queue :D